# XGBoost regressor hyperparameter tuning with hyperopt leads to overfit

Tags: python, regression, xgboost, overfitting, hyperparameter-tuning

Using hyperopt to hyperparameter tuning on XGBoost regressor, I am receiving overfiting on the train set.

There is any suggestion how to solve it ?

I have used cross validation with early_stopping_rounds and it still doesn't improved.

I have tried to tune the gamma,  colsample_bytree, subsample, max_depth, min_child_weight and eta and still couldn't reached to good enough results without overfitting.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Roi.